# Vuex modules and returning a promise in an action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I want to split my vuex file into modules, but as soon as I do that the promise I return from my action becomes undefined when I console log it in the actual template.

So in my action I have something like

```
return axios.get(....)
```

And in my component I have a method that does the following

```
this.$store.dispatch('setRules').then(response => {console.log(response)})
```

As soon as I switch from using store.js to importing a module in my store.js file, the response becomes undefined but the rest of vuex still works correctly. When checking the state I also see that the action actually gets executed and the state gets updated, so it seems as if it is a problem with axios.

The new store.js file looks the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import stock from './modules/stock';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store( {
    modules: {
        stock,
    }
});
```

And in my module stock.js I have something like this.

```
const getters = {..}
const actions = {..}
const mutations = {..}
const state = {..}

export default {
  namespaced: false,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is probably in the code for the `switch from using store.js to importing a module`. Can you show that in the question?

Comment: I've added it to the question.

Comment: are you sure you haven't forgotten to import axios in that module?

Comment: Yes 100% sure, I have imported it. Furthermore, the response on the get request made in the action is perfectly fine. It is just that the promise that this action returns suddenly is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that the problem was caused by the fact that I tried to acces `this.$store.state.x` while it should be `this.$store.state.stock.x`. Is there a way to not need the module name to access the state?

Comment: I think having the module name as part of the path is a good idea, as it avoids name clashes and helps keep things organized.

Answer (score 0):

The above scenerio is happening because javascript is asyncronous and hence before the response from your api call is returned the console statement is executed and hence you see that as undefined.

You can try using async await on axios call as

```
async actionName ()
{
  await axios.get(..).then(response => { console.log(response)} )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't think this is the problem. The exact same code worked fine before and actions can contain asynchronous code, that's why you use an action instead of a mutation anyway.